# What is the best way to show $\tau(t)=-\frac{(\alpha'\wedge\alpha'')\cdot\alpha'''}{{|\alpha'\wedge\alpha''|}^2}$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha: I\to R^3$ be a regular parametrized curve (not necessarily by arc length) and let $\beta:J\to R^3$ be a reparametrization of $\alpha(I)$ by the arc length $s=s(t)$, measured from $t_0\in I$. Let $t=t(s)$ be the inverse function of $s$ and set $d\alpha/dt=\alpha'$, $d^2\alpha/dt^2=\alpha''$, etc. Prove that the torsion of $\alpha$ at $t\in I$ is

$$\tau(t)=-\frac{(\alpha'\wedge\alpha'')\cdot\alpha'''}{{|\alpha'\wedge\alpha''|}^2}$$

I found it a bit hard to find a way to start because if I use the Frenet equations there will be some constants and on the numerator there is a third derivative of $\alpha$. Should I express $\alpha$ as $\alpha(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$? I don't think this will do much work.

Could anyone please give some hints or helps on the strategy?

Many many thanks! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

We'll do some derivatives of $\alpha$, then use the Frenet-Serret formulae to express them in terms of the basis. It should be clear what to do from there, given the form of the formula.
$$ \alpha' = \frac{d\alpha}{dt} = \frac{ds}{dt} \frac{d\alpha}{ds} := s' \dot{\alpha} = s' T, $$
the tangent vector, where $s$ is the arclength. Now differentiate again:
$$ \alpha'' = s'' T + s'^2 \dot{T} = s'' T + s'^2 \kappa N, $$
using the first F-S formula. (Here you can wedge the two equations together to find a formula for the curvature.) Differentiate one last time:
$$ \alpha''' = s''' T + s''s' \dot{T} +(2s's'' \kappa + s'^3 \dot{\kappa})N + s'^3 \kappa \dot{N} \\
= s''' T +(3s's'' \kappa + s'^3 \dot{\kappa})N + s'^3 \kappa (-\kappa T + \tau B) \\
= (s'''-s'^3\kappa^2) T +(3s's'' \kappa + s'^3 \dot{\kappa})N + s'^3 \kappa\tau B, $$
using the first two F-S formulae. Now you can isolate the torsion (although I think your sign may be the reverse of the usual one, which is such that $\dot{B}=-\tau N $).

Comment: What did you mean by isolate the torsion? Did you mean move $\tau$ to one side of the equation? But we want to write the final expression in terms of $\alpha$.

Comment: Look at the expression for the torsion you are trying to prove. What does $\alpha' \wedge \alpha''$ equal, in terms of the expressions I have derived?

Comment: Near enough. So since $\{T,N,B\}$ is an orthonormal basis, can you see how to get a scalar expression with $\tau$ in it?